# Write out a text file on Linux to be imported by Windows application, line break issues

Tags: java

I've read a lot of stuff both on stackoverflow and around the net, I've also tried a dozen variations in my code & am yet to find a solution.
The method has to write out a text file according to these file specs I was given, so that another application on a windows based system can import the file. Have discovered a test for this is that if the line breaks look correct in notepad then the import succeeds.

After the file is written to the server, it is then read again passed into a byte array that is later on attached to an email etc. (not sure it this would be relevant)

I started with the higher level classes I usually use to write out files, and as I read more on the subject, tried using FileOutputStream so I could specify the CRLF bytes explicitly. (Still doesn't align correctly in notepad which is the test I'm using)

```
byte[] CRLF = { 0x0D, 0x0D, 0x0A };//"If you write \r\n on Windows, you'll actually get 0x0D 0x0D 0x0A in the file"
     Map<String, ByteBuffer> fileMap = new HashMap<String, ByteBuffer>();
     //eg: BA20110627-2.TXT
     Timestamp nowTimestamp = UtilDateTime.nowTimestamp();
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
     String date = df.format(nowTimestamp);
     int count = 1;
     for(Map<String, List<String>> fileLineListsAndTotAmountMap : fileLineListsAndTotAmountMaps){
         String fileName = "BA"+date+"-"+count+".TXT";
         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileStorePath+fileName);
         String header = ""+new Header(date).toString();
         byte[] headerAsBytes = header.getBytes();
         out.write(headerAsBytes);
         out.write(CRLF);
         //each map only has one entry
         Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry = (Entry<String, List<String>>) fileLineListsAndTotAmountMap.entrySet().toArray()[0];
         for(String s: entry.getValue()){
                if (!s.equals("")) {
                    String line = s;
                    byte[] lineAsBytes = line.getBytes();
                    out.write(lineAsBytes);
                    out.write(CRLF);

                }
          }
         //totNumOfDebitRecords, totAmountForDebitRecords
         String footer = ""+new Footer(new Integer(fileLineListsAndTotAmountMap.size()).toString(), entry.getKey());
         byte[] footerAsBytes = footer.getBytes();
         out.write(footerAsBytes);
         out.write(CRLF);
         out.flush();
         out.close();
         fileMap.put(fileName, ByteBuffer.wrap(getBytesFromFile(new File(fileStorePath+fileName))));
      }
```

The only other thing I can think of trying is using maybe java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder & trying to encode it as ASCII though I can't really see how that would help.

Can anyone shed a little more light on this sort of issue?

Comment: If you are writing text, why aren't you using FileWriter instead of OutputStream?

Comment: My first pass used `new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter())` & `out.write(line + "\r\n");` "I started with the higher level classes..." it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't read the rest of your code yet, but this is already inaccurate:

```
//"If you write \r\n on Windows, you'll actually get 0x0D 0x0D 0x0A in the file"
byte[] CRLF = { 0x0D, 0x0D, 0x0A };
```

CRLF is just 0x0d, 0x0a...

Additional problems:

- You're using `String.getBytes()` without specifying an encoding: almost always a bad idea
- You're not using `finally` blocks for your streams
- You're using `""+x` to convert a value to a string - just call `toString` (in the case of `header` you've already *got* a string); `""+x` will work, but it's ugly code - it talks about concatenation, which isn't what you're trying to achieve.
- You should use a `Writer` (e.g. `OutputStreamWriter`) to write text data - that's what it's there for. Then you don't need to worry about the bytes, you can just work in terms of strings. I would strongly suggest `OutputStreamWriter` instead of `FileWriter` so that you can specify the encoding.

Once you've fixed all that, your code will be in a better position to fix the specific problem of line breaks... although I'd strongly recommend that if you're still having problems, you ask a question with a short but *complete* program which *just* prints a few lines of text. The header, footer etc are irrelevant to the business of "writing a line separator".

You may well find that the IO-related classes in [Guava](http://guava-library.googlecode.com/) make all of this easier, too...

Comment: "I've also tried a dozen variations" ... that's where the ugly code comes from (this code is in a unit test). My original attempt worked with Strings not bytes but the using `+ "\r\n"` as line separator, did not work, which is what lead me down this road.  would try using OutputStreamWriter but then I couldn't use `byte[] CRLF = { 0x0D, 0x0A };` (Tried that first & then found a ref to  0x0D, 0x0D, 0x0A) Can you think of any other helpful hints. Thanks

Comment: @justify: It's always a good idea when you ask a question to present the *cleanest* code you've tried, and then just mention other options as well. When you say it "did not work" that doesn't really tell us much about what you've seen... as I say, it would be helpful if you'd boil this down to *just* the relevant code - your actual business use is *not* relevant here. A short but complete example program showing trying to write some lines, and a description of the expected outcome vs actual outcome would help a lot.

Comment: Abstracting just that code into a clean stand alone method did help me to discover that it's only when the new file read off the disk & is attached to an email that the CRLF is actually lost. In future I will create a prototype before asking a question...thanks for the advice

Comment: @justify: Congrats on finding the problem - and yes, this sort of diagnostic work before asking a question is often enough to avoid the question being asked :) The good news is that even if it doesn't help you find the problem, it'll make the question itself better when you come to ask it - so hopefully you'll get help quicker.

Answer (score 0):

System.getProperty("line.separator") returns a String of the OS's newline chars
so this should return "\n" for linux and "\r\n" for Windows and so on.
Maybe it helps.